# Isolating DataFrame instances where column A = one specific code, but column B = multiple different descriptions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column is the account code and the secondary column is the description, and need to flag up instances where an account code has more than one description present. For example to take this:

```
  Acc. Code   Description
0      0001 Description 1
1      0002 Description 2
2      0002 Description 2
3      0003 Description 3 
4      0003       Desc. 3 
5      0004 Description 4
6      0005 Description 5
7      0006 Description 6
8      0006       Desc. 6 
9      0006     desc. Six 
10     0007 Description 1
```

and adjust it so I have a dataframe like this, which will later be used to choose which description to prioritise and map for all instances of that code:

```
  Acc. Code   Description
0      0003 Description 3 
1      0003       Desc. 3 
2      0006 Description 6
3      0006       Desc. 6 
4      0006     desc. Six
```

I haven't been able to find anything specific to pandas to filter for duplicates based on multiple column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` + `.filter()` where you you filter according `.nunique()` size:

```py
x = df.groupby("Acc. Code").filter(lambda x: x["Description"].nunique() > 1)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   Acc. Code    Description
2          3  Description 3
3          3        Desc. 3
6          6  Description 6
7          6        Desc. 6
8          6      desc. Six
```

Comment: I keep getting a blank dataframe? So is the x supposed to be the new filtered dataframe, whilst df is the old unfiltered one? I keep getting the x after lambda flagged up for shadowing name outside of scope no matter how i rename everything.

Comment: Edit: Apologies, there was an error higher in my script where it wasn't pulling the duplicate listing correctly. This method functions correctly but the only issue is this keeps duplicates that have the same description. So for example if there is code "0003" with "description 3" in the list multiple times, all of those will appear in the filtered list.

Answer (score 1):

Yuo can use value counts to filter your dataframe if those are the only columns

```
df[df['Code'].isin(df['Code'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x>1].index)]
```